# Eclipse can’t see my Android Device on Window.Previously I had been working fine

Tags: android

Eclipse can’t see my Android Device on Window.Previously I had been working fine.Suddenly I got This problem.How can i fix this:

[image]

I  have setuped these thing in my device:

1.USB debug mode:
2.Thick Unknown source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Drag the notification bar & click on "USB Connected" then click the button "Turn off USB storage" and "Turn on USB storage".Then Its ok

You may be clicked this option previously

Answer (score 2):

do you have set all necessary options at your device?
for correct settings look at this side: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

or have you already tried to reboot the device or disconnect and connect it again?

Comment: Yes.I have setup beasic thing for running my app.I was working fine testerday.Today only i got this kind of error

Comment: sometimes i've the same problem, but in my case i've just to remove the device from the usb port and connect it again.

Comment: When we coneected to USB drive into PC, that time it show usb connected icon notification bar